# Set-Acl error Active Directory permissions to computer account

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to use PowerShell to modify the access permissions to the computer account, adding other administrators.

I'm able to do using `dsacls` command line without problem like this command

```
dsacls (Get-ADComputer $computername).DistinguishedName /g mydomain\xx882372:GA
```

But when I try to do the same using PowerShell, I get an error with the `Set-Acl` command:

> Set-Acl : Access is denied
>
> At line:1 char:1

My PowerShell code is the following

```cs
$computername = 'mycomputer'
$aclpath = "AD:\" + (Get-ADComputer $computername).DistinguishedName
$act = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
$adrights = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights]::GenericAll
$who = (Get-ADUser -Identity xx882372).Sid
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $aclpath
$ace = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule -ArgumentList $who, $adrights, $act #, $inheritanceType
$acl.AddAccessRule($ace)
Set-Acl -Path $aclpath -AclObject $acl
```

Any idea what could be wrong with `Set-Acl`?

Comment: I seem to recall having issues with `Set-Acl` when the owner of an object wasn't the account running the cmdlet or one of its groups.

Comment: In this case, I'm the Owner of the computer Object (I already created it), and I've have assigned full access permissions to myself to this object